# Clicking a button that's being overruled by a permant overlay in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having an issue with permanent overlaying and now Selenium refuses to click since it will click the wrong button.

Is there a way to temporarly hide the wrong button untill the process is done and then re-enable the button? I'm using Chrome and Python with Selenium.

Comment: Can we get some code / examples?

Comment: You should probably try clicking with Javascript, if `.click()` is not working for you. JS click shouldn't care about the overlay, unless Selenium can't find the element at all. If you get `ClickIntercepted` error, JS click should work, but if you get `NoSuchElement` or `TimeoutException` then it's a different issue.

Comment: you can hide the overlay using javascript.... or click as Christine mentions above.  You can also click the overlay first, at which point I assume it'll disappear... the click may even bubble up/down and/or trigger the one you want.  It all depends on why that object is there in the first place.